# logging.error fail to capture error log

Tags: python, logging

I am learning logging module, but very confused with its usage

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
try:
    fp = open("file_not_exist.md")
    logging.error("File not exist in try")
except Exception as e:
    logging.debug("File not exist in except")
```

The above code, I'd like to get a log if the files to be opened not exist.

However, it output:

```
In [26]: !python test_logging.py
2018-08-28 23:15:53,835 - DEBUG - File not exist in except
```

`logging.error` unable to capture errors.

I revised it as:

```
try:
    fp = open("file_not_exist.md")
    logging.debug("File not exist in try")
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("File not exist in except")
```

It outputs:

```
In [28]: !python test_logging.py
2018-08-28 23:17:02,327 - ERROR - File not exist in except
```

The output is identical with logging.debug, it cannot distinguish "error" or "debug", just print the message.

I intend to make a good use of logging, but it seems the categories "debug, info, warning, error, critical" is just a verbose print.

What's problem with my example codes of applying logging?

Comment: Those messages aren't identical. One says `DEBUG`, the other says `ERROR`. Your `logging.x("File not exist in try")` will only be reached if the file in fact **does** exist. -- Have you tried the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial)?

Comment: I see, logging does not identify the levels automatically. @FHTMitchell could you please transmit the comment to the answer.